# Does class-instance relations can be bilateral?

Tags: python, class

How is that possible? the elements `type` and `object` are both classes and instances of each other? what i'm missing here?

```
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, because `object` and `type` are both defined in C, and that C code can be used to hack together a circular relationship between the two. This is necessary because:

1. Everything in Python is an object, including classes.
2. Every object must be an instance of some class.
3. `object` is the root parent class of all classes, including `type`.
4. `type` is the default class for all classes, including `object`.

Comment: Doesn't need to be defined in C to hack together a circular relationship; a class can override the `isinstance` check to return any value that it feels appropriate. This is used to implement the ABC classes; for example `isinstance(X, collections.abc.Hashable)` returns `True` for any X with a `__hash__` method. See [Customizing instance and subclass checks in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) and [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/).

Comment: @sabik: That's a good point, but I'm not sure how else to word it. Every language would have its own way to bootstrap a root `object` class.

Comment: I guess just that there's nothing C-specific about it; the same hack can be done in both C code and in Python code.

Answer (score 0):

In [`CPython` documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86d69444e7cfe758212956df0be0ec7b8a4251a6/Doc/c-api/typeobj.rst#type-objects) we can read:

> Perhaps one of the most important structures of the Python object system is the structure that defines a new type: the :c:type:`PyTypeObject` structure. Type objects can be handled using
>   any of the :c:func:`PyObject_\*` or :c:func:`PyType_\*` functions, but
>   do not offer much that's interesting to most Python applications.
>   These objects are fundamental to how objects behave, so they are very
>   important to the interpreter itself and to any extension module that
>   implements new types.
>
> Type objects are fairly large compared to most of the standard types. The reason for the size is that each type object stores a large
>   number of values, mostly C function pointers, each of which implements
>   a small part of the type's functionality.

**Bonus:**
Here is the [definition of the built-ins `type` and `object`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fe2978b3b940fe2478335e3a2ca5ad22338cdf9c/Include/object.h#L246-L247)